# Metric using measure in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a nonempty measure space with $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$, $|X| < \infty$, where $| \cdot |$ denotes the cardinality of a set. Also, let $\mathcal{A} = \{\emptyset, X\}$.

Define $d_\mu: \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{A} \to [0, \infty)$ such that $d_\mu(U, V) = | \mu(U) - \mu(V)|$.

Is $d_\mu$ a metric?

Recall that for any set $X$, we call $d: X \times X \to [0, \infty)$ a metric if for all $x,y$ and $z \in X$, the following holds:

1. $d(x,y) = 0 \iff x=y$
2. $d(x,y) = d(y, x)$
3. $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$

But I am stuck at the first property.

Comment: Your set has only two elements. You need only to check it case by case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is affirmative, but for trivial reasons. More generally, let $\mathcal{A}=\{a, b\}$ be any set with just two elements. For every injective function $f\colon \mathcal{A}\to \mathbb R$, the following is a metric on $\mathcal A$:
$$
d(x, y)=\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert.$$

Comment: What if $\mu$, a measure from some $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ measure space, can is injective? That is, if $U, V \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu(U) = \mu(V)$ implies $U = V$. Will $d_\mu$ work with any $\sigma$-algebra on $X$?

Comment: @JoshuaOrtiz: Maybe. But it is such a unlikely situation that it is not even worth thinking about it. Can you make me even one nontrivial example of a measure space with that property?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathcal A=\{\emptyset, X\}$ only has 2 elements and that $X$ is nonempty, it's easy to check each individual case:
$$d_\mu(X,X)=0$$
$$d_\mu(\emptyset,\emptyset) = 0$$
$$d_\mu(X,\emptyset) = |X|  >0$$
You can inmediatly conclude the first property holds looking at these. The other 2 can also be verified directly looking at the value of each particular case.